# Invalid block tag: 'gettweet', expected 'endblock' for Django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am learning Django, and I am trying to test getting a tweet with the twitter API and displaying it on a page.
my views.py says

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from firstsite.website import twit
# Create your views here.
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'firstsite/templates/index.html'
```

and my index.html says

```
{% extends "firstsite/templates/base/base.html" %}
{% block title %}The home page{% endblock %}
{% block base_content %}
{% gettweet %} 
{% endblock %}
```

twit.py says

```
from twython import Twython
import json
def gettweet():
    APP_KEY= 'somekey'
    APP_SECRET = 'somesecretkey'

    twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, oauth_version=2)
    ACCESS_TOKEN = twitter.obtain_access_token()
    twitter1 = Twython(APP_KEY, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
    data1 = twitter1.search(q='python', count=1)
    return(data1['statuses'][0]['text'])
```

When I try to access that view, I get this error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag: 'gettweet', expected 'endblock'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag: 'gettweet', expected 'endblock'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 331
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3.4
Python Version: 3.4.0
Python Path:    
['/home/lonewaft/webdev/firstsiteproject',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 7 Jun 2014 02:14:43 +0000
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error, please help me, thank you.

Comment: Where is `gettweet` coming from?

Comment: @alecxe i'll add that code as well, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a python function from a template this way. Call it in your view, [add the result to a template context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) and show it in the template:

```
import twit

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'firstsite/templates/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tweet'] = twit.gettweet()  
        return context
```

Then, in the template:

```
{% extends "firstsite/templates/base/base.html" %}

{% block title %}The home page{% endblock %}

{% block base_content %}
    {{ tweet }} 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, just had to change
`context['tweet'] = gettweet()`

to

`context['tweet'] = twit.gettweet()`

Comment: @lonewaft gotcha, edited the answer to follow your note.